# What does interpolate mean in the context of underscore.js's template function?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, interpolation

I'm trying to understand the difference between underscore's template method's markup types.

Specifically, I'm trying to figure out the difference between underscores <%- %> markup and <%= %> aside from HTML-escaping. Are there any other differences between the two types?

From underscore's documentation:

> If you wish to interpolate a value, and have it be HTML-escaped, use <%- … %>

What does interpolate mean in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Underscore will change the value of the parameter inside your <% %> declaration for example  <%-firstName %> for the value of the property firstname of the JSON you pass to the template. 
it means is replacing the variable declaration for the actual value. the diference of the - = is just that if you want this value to be HTML scaped.

Answer (score 4):

It means evaluate and populate..

Lets say you have

Lets say after you convert the `model attributes to JSON` this is the object

```
{
   title : 'Hello World',
   escapeTitle : '<Hello World >'    
};
```

If you do this

```
<%= {{title}} %>         // Displayed as -- Hello World 
<%= {{escapedTitle}} %>  // Displayed as -- &#60;Hello World&#62;
```

But if you use this

```
<%- {{escapedTitle}} %>  // Displayed as -- <Hello World>
```

So first it is evaluated if there are any characters if the user wants to be escaped and then populates it

Answer (score 0):

interpolate means to evaluate a javascript expression and place the resulting value within the template data. For example:

```
_.template('Hello, <%- name %>', {name: 'Tony'})
```

will return `Hello, Tony`. That's interpolation, as opposed to evaluation, which is where you can you expressions for control flow or other expressions whose purpose is not just to compute a value that will become part of the template output string.

Comment: But calling `_.template('Hello, <%= name %>', {name: 'Tony'})` is the same as calling `_.template('Hello, <%- name %>', {name: 'Tony'})`

Comment: Not the same, but both interpolation. `<%=` is direct interpolation and `<%-` is interpolation with automatic HTML escaping.